# Entityframework query, only select if variable is not null else don't select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this kind of query:

```
 var p = form p in db.table 
     where(p.Id ==  variable1  && p.proId == variable2 ...)
     select p.Tolist();
```

and for eg. if variable 1 is null don't compare that condition in where clause just take the where clause

```
where (p.proId == variable2 ...)
```

Is there any way to do this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just `null` check in the `where` clause?

```
where((variable1 == null || p.Id == variable1) 
    && (variable2 != null && p.proId == variable2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simple like this:

```
 where((variable1 == null || p.Id ==  variable1) && p.proId == variable2 ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers here *will* work, you tagged your question entity-framework, and anytime you're writing LINQ-to-Entities, it's very important to have your `IQueryable`/`IEnumerable` boundary firmly in mind, because only fully `IQueryable` compliant code is efficiently convertible to SQL (and many times, e.g., `string.Format`, is not convertible at all).

```
var q = null != variable1
    ? from p in db.table
      where p.Id == variable1
      where p.proId == variable2
      select p
    : from p in db.table
      where p.proId == variable2
      select p;
```

Note that, if writing LINQ-to-Objects instead, the other answers given are much more efficient, concise, and readable:

```
var q = from p in someEnumerable
        where null == variable1 || p.Id == variable1
        where p.proId == variable2
        select p;
```

Note: I left off the `.ToList()` to keep the query as an `IQueryable` (or `IEnumerable`) because there are so many times you actually wish to enumerate through the query only once, or project to something simpler before resolving the query (e.g., `select p.Id`). This is especially important in the case of L2E, because everything you do before the `.ToList()` (or `.ToArray()` or `.Load()`) is *directly convertible to SQL*, which is the most powerful way to use EF.